# Issue with Configuration & Menu

Tags: 7, routes

I am trying to add a section to the configuration page using [hook_menu](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) and add a single entry in the section.

Two modules, the first defines the section on the configuration page.

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_menu().
 */
function parent_menu() {
  $items = array();

  // Create local grouping for any custom module that defines a
  // configuration page.
  $items['admin/config/p'] = array(
    'title'            => 'Parent Configuration',
    'description'      => 'Manage configuration for Custom Modules.',
    'position'         => 'right',
    'page callback'    => 'system_admin_menu_block_page',
    'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
    'file'             => 'system.admin.inc',
    'file path'        => drupal_get_path('module', 'system')
  );
  return $items;
}
```

Second module defines the actual configuration page for one of the custom modules. The idea is that as we add more and more custom modules, we can define a new configuration page inside the parent configuration section.

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_menu().
 */
function child_menu() {
  $items = array();

  // settings
  $items['admin/config/p/child'] = array(
    'title'            => 'Child Settings',
    'description'      => 'Administrative settings for Child.',
    'page callback'    => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments'   => array('child_settings'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer child'),
    'file'             => 'child.admin.inc',
  );

  return $items;
}
```

`admin/config/p/child` works and I'm able to modify the settings for the module. `admin/config/p` also works but does not show any sub-links. `admin/config` does not show the section I've defined.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Disabling, un-installing and re-installing the modules did the trick...